# Passing a long string for a param value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, omniauth

I am using Omniauth to make users sign up with Facebook account. When they first click on the auth link, I direct them to the sign up page for them to put some additional information, unless they already have an account for my application.

*SessionsController*

```
 def create_facebook
        #make an environment variable
        auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
        if User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"])
            user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"])
            session[:user_id] = user.id
            redirect_to lessons_path, flash[:notice] => "Signed in!"
        else
            #go to signup page to get additional info
            redirect_to new_user_path(:auth => auth) #problem
        end
  end
```

In this case, I'm passing the entire auth hash using a parameter in the URL because I want to call `User.create_with_omniauth(auth)` in `Users#new`. Should I avoid from doing it? What are the other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few approaches that I can see:

- Store the auth value in the user's session (but bear in mind that the session doesn't encrypt values by default; it only signs them), and then pull them out when viewing the new user action.

Alternatively:

- Just call the new user action code directly (either share it via a helper, or if it's on the same controller - call the action and then make sure you call `render` to set up the correct view)

A third and more robust alternative that is similar to the session approach, but a little more heavyweight:

- Set up the user with what information you have at this step (and set them to some sort of "partially registered" state).  Sign them in.  Then make sure you read in any existing data when viewing the new_user action.  Might also want to set up your routing layer to always redirect users in this state to the sign up page no matter where they are.

Comment: Nice input. How do you think about the update in my other question in here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543132/rails-omniauth-hash